# Dynamic Rows in C# for Web Services

Tags: c#, sql, web-services, dynamic, datatable

I have a dynamic query with a pivot from sql to c #, the problem is that I do not know how to put dynamic rows and columns to print them through a web services

```
DataSet dt= new DataSet();
 DataTable table = dt.Tables[0];
   String reg= "";
 for (int i = 0; i < tabla.Rows.Count; i++)
                   {
                   int c = 1;
                  Array array = tabla.Rows[i].ItemArray;
                   reg += array.GetValue(0).ToString() + ",";
                   reg += array.GetValue(1).ToString() + ",";
                   .
                   .
                   .
                   reg += array.GetValue(n).ToString() + "*";
```

What I would like is that the part of the "reg" was dynamic. Thank you very much
PD: is important that the last one have the "*"

Comment: Can you send the dataset to the webservice and do what you want in the webservice and print from the webservice
Just send the dataset to the webservice

Comment: @HopeMystery 
Yes, but I need to print in chains, the number of rows varies, which is why they must be dynamic, can you help me?

Comment: i guess you can copy first 5 rows to another dataset and call the webservice then copy next 5 rows to another dataset and call the webservice ... etc